# C#/ASP.NET JSON date deserialize

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, datetime, deserialization

I'm trying to deserilize an object the following code, and I'm wondering what the proper regex would be to replace json dates.  When I run the following code, the regex never gets triggered.  I'm using the standard JSON date format inside the json string.

```
{
    "UniqueId": "1000000003",     
    "Id": 3, 
    "ModifyTimestamp": "/Date(1338857699743)/"         
}

string json = // see above
string p = @"\\/Date\((\d+)\+\d+\)\\/";
MatchEvaluator matchEvaluator = new MatchEvaluator(convertJsonDateToDateString);
Regex reg = new Regex(p);
json = reg.Replace(json, matchEvaluator);
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();            
Student student = serializer.Deserialize<Student>(json) as Student; 



public static string convertJsonDateToDateString(Match m) {
        string result = string.Empty;
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(long.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value));
        dt = dt.ToLocalTime();
        result = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a fully working solution:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ResolveOverlapIssue
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static void DoSomethingElse<T>(ref T Id)
        {
            int i = 00;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string json = "{" +
                          "UniqueId: 1000000003," +
                          "Id: 3," +
                          "ModifyTimestamp: /Date(1338857699743)/" +
                          "}";

            MatchEvaluator matchEvaluator = ConvertJsonDateToDateString;
            var reg = new Regex(@".Date\(\d+\)\/.");
            json = reg.Replace(json, matchEvaluator);

        }

        public static string ConvertJsonDateToDateString(Match m)
        {
            var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(long.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value));
            dt = dt.ToLocalTime();
            var result = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I actually have about 5 or 6 dates in the object, so I won't know what the actual date is.  What could I put inside the <ticks> to have it pick up the actual number as a Regex value as well?

Comment: My edit might be a little better... Are you saying that you need to pick out a specific date?

Comment: I think I'm not being clear either :)  I want to take ANY date that gets passed in and convert it into a C# DateTime. I won't know what the date looks like other than it will be in this format: /Date(1306123200000)/  -- I tried your above edit which did not trigger my matching function.  And I want to do this work in C# as I have coded above, (or in some simpler fashion if possible)

Comment: The regex seems to work OK... look at my code below...

string value = "/Date(1338857699743)/";
var reg = new Regex("^/Date\\((\\d+)\\)/$");
var match = reg.Match(value);
(match.Success == true)

Comment: Hmm... if that's the case, then perhaps my approach in the C# code is incorrect.

Comment: Wait - Try this:
var reg = new Regex("^*/Date\\((\\d+)\\)/*$");
Once you do "m.Groups[0]"<- zero - you will need to substring/replace the extra crap...
I THINK this will do the grunt work for the removing crap for you:
new Date(parseInt(value.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10))

Comment: Once you decide that everything is working OK, feel free to upvote the hell out of me, I need the points ;)

Comment: I'm wondering if it's even executing the regex at all.  my MatchEvaluator is never getting invoked... although I'm assuming it only gets invoked if a match is found?

Comment: Yeah, it only runs is a match is found.  Put a breakpoint on "Regex reg = new Regex(p);"
then put this in your "watch" window:
"reg.Match(json).Success"

Comment: Yeah, it never hits with this new Regex(@"^*/Date\((\\d+)\)/*$")

Comment: Can you paste a working (sample) on pastebin or somewhere else so that I can see exactly what you are doing and try to debug it?  It's 04:04 here in the UK so I'm going to sleep soon... But I can hang around and help you out first...

Comment: Oops, sorry I left out the function, though you can grab it above.

Comment: @AdamLevitt hahahaha, StackOverflow appears to be changing what I write... I checked pastebin and it's right on there: http://pastebin.com/jtTaJmSq

Don't forget to upvote me... It's worth it, like pantenne...

Comment: I'm going to put another episode of oz on, so you have about an hour to come back to me...

Comment: I must be crazy.  I tried your latest Regex, and the match evaluator STILL isn't getting invoked.  I'm thinking my code must be incorrect.

Comment: @AdamLevitt I'm going crazy, I could have sworn it worked just two minutes ago... Time to sit up and pay attention... bbiab

Comment: @AdamLevitt right.  Sorry to mess you about, or to have messed you about... Here is a fully working solution.  I can see it firing the correct method when it should and not firing when it shouldn't.  

http://pastebin.com/fhjSx6gD

Comment: The extra backslash before \d should be removed

Answer (score 0):

`@"\\/Date` portion look wrong. It probably should be either `@"\/Date..."` or  `"\\/Data..."`. (same for trailing `"...\\/"`)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... isn't that what I already have? -- string p = @"\\/Date\((\d+)\+\d+\)\\/";

Comment: No.Vijay have it correct in his answer - no double escaping of `\` as you get in case of using `@` in front of string: `@"\\"` produces 2 back slashes, `"\\"` produces just one.